# How to use formTag in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm a beginner who recently started using Next.js.

## What I Want to do

I'm thinking of implementing a form in Next.js to specify an amount and use it to call the Ethereum API.

## Problem

I set up a form and tried to enter a value and onSubmit, but the process did not proceed.

## My code

Also, at this stage, we are not actually passing the amount to the API, but specifying it directly.

For example, when I enter 0.2 in the form and submit, the console shows hello1,amount=0.2,hello2,hello3 in that order and no other console.log is shown. In other words, the API has stopped running.

```
import * as zksync from "zksync";
import Layout from '../pages/components/Layout'
import { Contract, utils, ethers } from 'ethers'
import zkswapABI from '../zkswap.ABI.json'
import { useState } from 'react'


export default function OutsideUsageExample() {
  const MNEMONIC = process.env.MENMONIC;
  let ABI = zkswapABI;

  const ethersProvider = ethers.getDefaultProvider("ropsten");

  const ethWallet = ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(MNEMONIC).connect(ethersProvider);
  const contract = new Contract('0x010254cd670aCbb632A1c23a26Abe570Ab2Bc467', ABI, ethWallet)

  async function withdrawETH() {
    console.log("hello2");

    const syncProvider = await zksync.getDefaultProvider("ropsten");
    const syncWallet = await zksync.Wallet.fromEthSigner(ethWallet, syncProvider);

    const withdraw =
      await
        syncWallet.withdrawFromSyncToEthereum({
          ethAddress: ethWallet.address,
          token: "ETH",
          amount: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.001"),
        });

    console.log("withdraw=", withdraw);

    console.log(await withdraw.awaitReceipt());
    console.log(await withdraw.awaitVerifyReceipt());
  }


  async function depositETH() {
    console.log("hello3");

    const tx = await contract.depositETH(ethWallet.address, {
      value: utils.parseEther('0.1')
    })
    console.log("tx=", tx);
    return tx
  }

  async function zkSyncToZKSwap() {
    console.log("hello1");
    console.log("amount = ", event.target.amount.value);
    withdrawETH();
    depositETH();
  }



  return (
    <><Layout>
    </Layout><>
        <div>
          <section className="h-screen w-4/5 max-w-5xl mx-auto flex items-center justify-center flex-col">
            <form onSubmit={zkSyncToZKSwap}>
              <div className="flex flex-col rounded-lg overflow-hidden sm:flex-row">
                <label htmlFor="amount"></label>
                <input className="py-3 px-4 bg-gray-200 text-gray-800 border-gray-300 border-2 outline-none placeholder-gray-500 focus:bg-gray-100" id="amount" type="text" amount="amount" placeholder="Amount" />
                <button className="py-3 px-4 bg-gray-700 text-gray-100 font-semibold uppercase hover:bg-gray-600" type="submit" >Exchange</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </section>
        </div>
      </></>
  )
}
```

In fact, the browser will be reloaded and zkSyncToZKSwap and the two functions behind it that are supposed to be called will be aborted. Does anyone know the cause of this bug?

By the way, I have succeeded in hitting the API directly before setting up the form.

Comment: Try using `event.preventDefault();` in the first line inside `zkSyncToZKSwap`. You'll need to add an `event` param to that function as well.

Comment: Thank! I using ```event.preventDefault();``` , go well!